# Speeding up clustering/heatmap creation

Tags: r, optimization, plot, statistics, cluster-analysis

I am clustering and making a heatmap out of a fairly small matrix (5000 rows by 200 columns) but I find that with the standard `heatmap`-like functions in R, it takes forever. Example:

```
data <- replicate(5000, rnorm(200)) 
aheatmap(data, dist="correlation")
```

(this is using `aheatmap` from NMF package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/index.html)

the results seem a bit faster if using `euclidean` rather than `correlation` distance. Is there a way to speed this up?

to clarify I am only interested in clustering the columns not the rows so I often pass `aheatmap` the argument `Rowv=FALSE`

Comment: If you profile `aheatmap`, you'll see that most of the time is spend in `grid.Call.graphics` and `dist`. I would consider ways to aggregate the data before plotting. The output doesn't look like it needs this high resolution in the heatmap.

Comment: @Roland: I think dist needs to be computed 200 choose 2 times to compute all pairs... not sure how to avoid this but I don't see why computing correlations is so slow in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing far more comparisons in `dist` than you might have suspected. You are computing *5000* choose 2, and not *200* choose 2 comparisons. Perhaps this isn't what you want, but it is doing that in the code.

As @Roland points out, most of the time is spent in `dist`, which further makes it clear that this is where the problem is. Here is a sample on my machine:

```
data <- replicate(1500, rnorm(200)) 
system.time(aheatmap(data, dist="correlation"))
   user  system elapsed 
  27.69    0.64   28.33 
system.time(dist(1 - cor(data))) # A line that is in aheatmap
   user  system elapsed 
  21.26    0.02   21.28
```

The `dist` function is implemented with a C function in R, so you would expect it to be fast.

When you run `cor(data)`, it will give you a 5000x5000 matrix, (or 1500x1500 in my smaller test case), which is then used by `dist`. This means that my computer was computing

```
choose(1500,2) / 21
[1] 53535.71
```

roughly 53535.71 comparisons per second, which is pretty fast, I think. You aren't going to get much difference unless you reduce the number of comparisons being made.

---

If you want to stop computing the clustering for your 5000 columns, you can pass `NA` to the `Colv` argument, as noted in `?aheatmap`.

```
aheatmap(data,distfun="correlation",Rowv=NA) # No clustering on rows.
aheatmap(data,distfun="correlation",Colv=NA) # No clustering on columns.
```

Notably, passing `FALSE` will still compute the dendogram (the slow part), but it will not display it, while `NA` will not even compute the dendogram.

Comment: Since I only want to cluster the columns, how can I get it to only do 200 choose 2 computations at least? There's no need to do 5000 choose 2 since I am not clustering rows

Comment: You have 5000 columns. If you want to cluster columns, you will need 5000 choose 2 comparisons. However, see my update for shutting off row or column dendograms.

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing you can do is (at least in terms of random data), is to switch the columns and rows:

```
data <- replicate(200, rnorm(2000)) 
system.time(aheatmap(data, dist="euclidean",Colv=F))
user 15.048 sys  0.028 elapsed 15.370 

data <- replicate(2000, rnorm(200)) 
system.time(aheatmap(data, dist="euclidean",Rowv=F))
user 19.508 sys  0.164 elapsed 22.043
```

There seems to be a consistent gain.

The function does not seem to offer anything in the documentation in terms of making it faster, and I have no experience with the function/package myself.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a gain if you cluster just columns and tell heatmap to ignore rows; then the order is always ~200 instead of 5000. Also this gain is marginal... I don't see why this should take more than a minute or two, but it takes 15-20 minutes (!) here.

Comment: @user248237dfsf I took the least difference between the two. In some cases it is half the time. Maybe it is badly written code, I do not know. It seems to draw everything twice for me for some reason, which might be part of the slow down. Also, I am ignoring it to tell one dimension, like you suggested?